# ¿Como cambiar de storyboard correctamente?

Tags: swift3, uitableviewcontroller

Estoy usando un table view con una cantidad de rows concreta que permite cambiar a otras pantallas del proyecto, sin embargo cuando cambio a otro storyboard el navigation controller no me permite regresar.

mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Product", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProductViewController") as UIViewController
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break
        default: break
    }
}
```

Esto me permite ver el view controller del otro storyboard, me gustaría poder conservar el navigation controller.

Logre hacer esto por medio del storyboard reference, aunque no he puedo asignar los cambios dependiendo de la celda tocada.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para seguir utilizando el navigation controller deberias hacer un push cambiando esta linea de código:

```
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

por esta:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

y si es que los cambios los queres ver en el *viewController* destino (no sé si  entendí bien y si te referías a eso) para poder asignar los cambios según las celda tocada, el *viewController* destino, que en este caso es *vc*, debería tener una propiedad y simplemente la asignas antes de hacer el push. Por ejemplo:

```
vc.index = indexPath.row
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me enrede por una tonteria jajajaja XD.

Comment: Todo bien! ;) Me alegro de haberte ayudado